Any member of the team can only work on a single task (In Progress) at any one time. youtrack workflow
On-change
On-schedule
Basic state-machine
State-machine per issue type
Action
Custom
in which module its fit
and js code
js workflow code....
The team wants to use YouTrack Cloud to track their issues.
The team has one Scrum board.
There are two types of issues in the project – User stories and tasks. The type is defined via the Type field.
User stories and tasks are linked with parent-child relationships (there is no predefined mapping here, feel free to link them manually).
The board backlog contains only User stories that don’t belong to the board.

It should be possible to implement by writing a JS script for an on-change workflow rule. Any time an issue becomes In Progress, a search can be made to check if there are any issues already in progress with the same assignee. If the search results are not empty, the transaction can be blocked using the workflow.check method.
You can also use WIP indicators. With this, the column will turn red whenever max WIP is exceeded. In your case, this can help if each team member creates a personal board and tracks their issues there

can you give me code
